# CLI Automation for Windows and Mac

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I want to do CLI Automation for Windows, Mac and UNIX Is there an existing framework that I can use of. For Web and API automation I am using `Node.js`

Things I need to do are following

1. Open terminal and brew install ..... on successful completion of this
2. brew upgrade abc/xyz/tcd
3. export tbc=xyz
4. abc setup ->I will need to interact with terminal here depending upon output I will be entering the password here
5. Once the password is entered it gives options to select language. I should be able to toggle between options and select whichever is required and download the folder with files
6. I want to compare these files with existing file

Comment: bash shell scripting?

Comment: Yes but needed to work on both Mac, Windows and Linux, nice to able to run in node.js framework